# Make ExtJS member variable private

Tags: javascript, extjs

```
Ext.define("rgpd.user.Profile", {

    config: {
        id: -1,
        role: 0,
        token: '',
        corps_metier: [],
    },

    constructor: function(config) {
        this.initConfig(config);
        this.callParent(arguments);
    }
});
```

I have this class definition. I need to have a global access to this and the object values (using getters and setters) but the member variables (id, token, role etc.) have to be unreachable from console. I tried using [private property](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.0.0/classic/Ext.Class.html#cfg-privates) but it didn't work

edit:

from the example given

```
Ext.application({ name : 'Fiddle',

launch : function() {
    Ext.Msg.alert('Fiddle', 'Welcome to Sencha Fiddle!');
}

});

Ext.define('MyWindow', (function (){
    var isWindow = true;

    var isPrivateProp = true;



   return {
       isWindow: isWindow
   };
})());

var myWindow = new MyWindow();
console.log('object: ', MyWindow);
console.log('isWindow: ', myWindow.isWindow);
console.log('isPrivateProp: ', myWindow.isPrivateProp);

myWindow.isPrivateProp = false;
console.log('isPrivateProp: ', myWindow.isPrivateProp);
```

if i do this isPrivateProp value is reset to false. I want the property to be accessible ONLY using my getters function and i want to be able to change the property value ONLY using my setters

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A basic example of a pattern which can be applied with ExtJs to have private members:

```
Ext.define(‘MyButton’, (function(){
  function privateStaticMethod() {
    console.log(‘static method’);
  }

  function privateMethod(me) {
    console.log(me.getText());
  };

  function privateMethod2() {
    console.log(this.getText());
  }

  return {
    extends: ‘Ext.button.Button’,
    text: 'Click me',

    // will be called when the button was clicked
     handler: function() {
      privateStaticMethod();
      privateMethod(this);
      privateMethod2.apply(this);
    }
};

})()
);
```

Source:
http://flexblog.faratasystems.com/index.php/private-methods-in-ext-js/

Edit:
Go to https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor

paste this code observe console:

```
Ext.application({
    name : 'Fiddle',

    launch : function() {
        Ext.Msg.alert('Fiddle', 'Welcome to Sencha Fiddle!');
    }
});


    Ext.define('MyWindow', (function (){
        var isWindow = true;

        var isPrivateProp = true;



       return {
           isWindow: function () { return isWindow }
       };
    })());

    var myWindow = new MyWindow();
    console.log('object: ', MyWindow);
    console.log('isWindow: ', myWindow.isWindow);
    console.log('isPrivateProp: ', myWindow.isPrivateProp);
```

Comment: how can i use this for my issue ?

Comment: @RomAZE check my edit, don't forget to accept  the answerif it helps you

Comment: and where do i define my getters and setters ? (for example getRole() and setCorpsMetier() )

Comment: You are reassigning the value of the object. You can do that. There is no way I am aware of you can not override a prop, it's a js thing.